# Sending array to storage on firestore is causing reading bytelength typeError

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-storage

```
app.post('/uploaduserdata', function(req, res){
  UploadFile(req.body.file)

  res.sendStatus(200)
}

//different file
export function UploadFile(file){
  console.log("hello testing")
  const storageRef = sRef(fileStore, "/working");
  console.log(file)
  // 'file' comes from the Blob or File API
  uploadBytes(storageRef, file).then((snapshot) => {
    console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
  });
}
```

this is the printout i get from the file

```
[
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0,
  ... 1124 more items
]
```

So im getting an array and the upload file does work since i tried it with a local image before. But now im sending an array from my client software.

Ive tried to read the file as a array million ways. If there is another body im not reading and just getting the length of the array.

It says blob or fileapi but its the same code for sending an array too.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'byteLength')
    at file:///C:/Users/uname/Desktop/ETRestAPI/node_modules/@firebase/storage/dist/node-esm/index.node.esm.js:1223:38
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at FbsBlob.getBlob (file:///C:/Users/uname/Desktop/ETRestAPI/node_modules/@firebase/storage/dist/node-esm/index.node.esm.js:1222:25)
    at multipartUpload (file:///C:/Users/uname/Desktop/ETRestAPI/node_modules/@firebase/storage/dist/node-esm/index.node.esm.js:1784:26)
    at uploadBytes$1 (file:///C:/Users/uname/Desktop/ETRestAPI/node_modules/@firebase/storage/dist/node-esm/index.node.esm.js:2915:25)
    at uploadBytes (file:///C:/Users/uname/Desktop/ETRestAPI/node_modules/@firebase/storage/dist/node-esm/index.node.esm.js:3416:12)
    at UploadFile (file:///C:/Users/uname/Desktop/ETRestAPI/getmodule.js:94:3)
    at file:///C:/Users/uname/Desktop/ETRestAPI/index.js:103:3
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\uname\Desktop\ETRestAPI\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\uname\Desktop\ETRestAPI\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
```

Answer (score 1):

solved it by

```
  uploadBytes(storageRef, new Uint8Array(file)).then((snapshot) => {
    console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
  });
```

Did not think it mattered but it really did matter, now the array uploads.